# Python: pexpect does not execute `backtick` command

Tags: python, bash, pexpect

I'm trying to run this command:

```
foo=`ls /`
```

Works perfectly on bash but not if I execute it via pexpect:

```
p = pexpect.spawn("foo=`ls /`").interact()

// Gives error command was not found or not executable: foo=`ls
```

What is the cause and how do I fix it? I've even tried escaping the ` but it seems its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are trying to execute requires `bash`. `pexpect` does not pass your command through `bash`, instead invoking your executable directly as if it were the shell.

From [the docs](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn):

> Remember that Pexpect does NOT interpret shell meta characters such as
>   redirect, pipe, or wild cards (>, |, or *). This is a common mistake.
>   If you want to run a command and pipe it through another command then
>   you must also start a shell. For example:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "ls -l | grep LOG > log_list.txt"')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Although the documentation doesn't mention them, this would certainly also apply to backticks. So write your code to invoke `bash` explicitly:

```
p = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "foo=`ls /`"').interact()
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! The p.sendline and p.expect still works which is exactly what I needed.